# kubeadm - ERROR start version '' not supported

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

Recently I upgraded Kubernetes cluster from version 1.5.3 to 1.6.1 using `kubeadm`.

Now I would like to upgrade from version 1.6.1 to 1.6.2 but I'm facing this error:

```
[root@master ~]#kubeadm upgrade plan --v=5
I1113 14:14:31.046080    8368 plan.go:67] [upgrade/plan] verifying health of cluster
I1113 14:14:31.046233    8368 plan.go:68] [upgrade/plan] retrieving configuration from cluster
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
I1113 14:14:31.111668    8368 common.go:122] running preflight checks
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
I1113 14:14:31.111843    8368 preflight.go:78] validating if there are any unsupported CoreDNS plugins in the Corefile
I1113 14:14:31.143841    8368 preflight.go:103] validating if migration can be done for the current CoreDNS release.
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR CoreDNSUnsupportedPlugins]: start version '' not supported
    [ERROR CoreDNSMigration]: start version '' not supported
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

It seems that `kubeadm` is not able to resolve CoreDNS version.

Here is the CoreDNS config:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2018-12-15T00:02:45Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "45537229"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: c01fbb58-fffc-11e8-9a01-005056a31666
```

From where it is reading the version number? Or what can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I discovered the cause of the problem. The `coredns` pod was terminated and could not resurect itself.

So I removed the pod by:

```
kubectl -n kube-system delete pod coredns-79ff88449c-4gjzs --grace-period=0 --force
```

And then installed it manually using `deploy.sh` script from https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes like this:

```
./deploy.sh | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now `kubeadm upgrade` works again like a charm.

And it seems that `kubeadm` reads CoreDNS version from the running pod.

Answer (score 1):

You received failed `CoreDNSUnsupportedPlugins` check due to `proxy` plugin that has been replaced with `forward` plugin. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82889) you can find more information about that.

**There are two ways to  solve this:**

- One is to ignore checks using
  `--ignore-preflight-errors=CoreDNSUnsupportedPlugins` at the time of 
  the upgrade.
- Second one is to replace `proxy . /etc/resolv.conf` from coredns
  configMap with `forward`.It should look like this:

  `forward . /etc/resolv.conf`

You can find more information about the same problem [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82889)

Comment: I already use `forward` plugin and not `proxy` as you can see in the CoreDNS config in my question. It is a different issue. Anyway thanks for the response.